# Pixel color comparisons in Opengl

Tags: opengl, floating-point, integer

I am developing a simple game which requires color comparison of 2 pixels. I have used glColor3f to set color. I read pixel color with following code. But I cannot compare float values. Will typecasting to integer and comparing work ? Will typecasting float to integer yield same result always.
glColor3i doesn't seem to work. How can I compare color values exactly ?

```
float r,g,b;
GLubyte pixel[3];
            glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
            r = pixel[0]/255.0;
            g = pixel[1]/255.0;
            b = pixel[2]/255.0;
```

Comment: What do you mean by compare? You can do less than / greater than / equals comparisons on the bytes directly; no need to convert them to a different format.

Comment: Means I can glColor3ub() to set color. Then retrieve and compare as bytes ?